# play 2.0 serve static file

Tags: static, playframework

I want localhost/assets/abc.png file to be served from project_root/assets/abc.png

GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)

With the routes above, localhost/assets/abc.png won't be served( I couldn't find a way)
but localhost/assets/images/abc.png will be served from root/assets/images/abc.png.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following entry at the bottom of `routes`:

```
# Serves only abc.png from root public folder
GET     /$file<abc.png>        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

That said, if you have multiple files to serve like this, better put them in a subfolder